# Как исправить код (JAVA Servlet + MySQL)

Tags: java, sql

Я написал сайт, там должно в таблице вывести ФИО студентов из БД(MySQL) + я могу через таблицу добавлять ФИО нового студента в БД и удалять. Я написал сервлет и JSP, но почему то не работает.

Мой сервлет с запросами SQL

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Добавлен</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1> Добавлнен в класс из " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String surname = request.getParameter("surname");

    }

    public void show() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        try {
            String sql = "select * from student";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_db_newnew?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=GMT", "root", "123456");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                rs.getString("name");
                rs.getString("surname");

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;

    }

    public String insertstudent() throws SQLException {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO student (name, surname) VALUES(?,?);";
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement prep = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_db_newnew?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=GMT", "root", "123456");
            prep = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            prep.setString(1, "name");
            prep.setString(2, "surname");

            prep.executeUpdate();
            prep.close();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return "successfully added";
    }

    public String delete() throws SQLException {

        String sql = "delete INTO student (name, surname) VALUES(?,?);";
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement prep = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_db_newnew?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=GMT", "root", "123456");
            prep = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return "successfully delete";
    }

}
```

Мой JSP 
AddStudent

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>fSchool</title>




    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/addstudent.css">



    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">
    <script src="js/jquery1111.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>



</head>

<body class="home-page">
    <div class="wrap-body">
        <header>
            <div id="cssmenu" >
                <ul>
                   <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>FSchool</span></a></li>
                   <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Students</span></a>
                      <ul>
                                              <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Show All Students</span></a>
                            <ul>
                               <li><a href="#"><span>Add</span></a></li>
                               <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Remove</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                         </li>


                      </ul>
                   </li>
                   <li><a href="archive.html"><span>Media</span></a></li>
                   <li><a href="single.html"><span>Skills</span></a></li>
                   <li class="last"><a href="contact.html"><span>About</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>


            </div>

     <div class="addstudent">
         <h1>Add Student</h1>
            <form action="MyServlet" method="Post">
            name : <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>     
            surname : <input type="text" name="surname"><br><br>
            <input hidden="true" value="addstudent" name="actionname">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
        </form>
         </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Мой JSP 
RemoveStudent

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>fSchool</title>




    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/RemoveStudent.css">



    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">
    <script src="js/jquery1111.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>



</head>

<body class="home-page">
    <div class="wrap-body">
        <header>
            <div id="cssmenu" >
                <ul>
                   <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>FSchool</span></a></li>
                   <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Students</span></a>
                      <ul>
                                              <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Show All Students</span></a>
                            <ul>
                               <li><a href="#"><span>Add</span></a></li>
                               <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Remove</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                         </li>


                      </ul>
                   </li>
                   <li><a href="archive.html"><span>Media</span></a></li>
                   <li><a href="single.html"><span>Skills</span></a></li>
                   <li class="last"><a href="contact.html"><span>About</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>


            </div>


            </table


    <div class="RemoveStudent">
         <h1>Remove Student</h1>
    <form action="MyServlet" method="post">
         Name:<input type="text" name="name" >
         Surname:<input type="text" name="surname">


            <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
            </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: А что именнго у вас не работает ? Не записывается в бд или не приходит запрос, или что ?

Comment: Если jsp не используется то зачем тогда сервлет?